# How to pass $scope to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a scope to a factory and use it in the controller where the function should be invoked, but it just doesn't work.

```
var myApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myApp.factory("UserService", function ($http) {
var users = ["xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz"];

return {
    all: function () {
        return users;
        console.log( users );
    },
    first: function () {
        return users[1];
    },
    checkUser: function(elUrl, classHide, classShow){
        $http.post(elUrl)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (!data.isMember) {
                el = classHide //should be when invoking: $scope.mailexist = classHide;
                $('form').submit();
            } else {
                el = classShow //should be when invoking: $scope.mailexist = classShow;
                return false;
            }
        }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            //$scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
            "<hr />status: " + status +
            "<hr />headers: " + header +
            "<hr />config: " + config;
        });
    }
};
});
 myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', function ($scope, $http, UserService) {

UserService.checkUser( 'inc/memberSearch.jsp?user.Email=' + $scope.umail + '&group.PK=' + angular.element('.grp').val(),
            $scope.mailexist,
            'mail-exist-hide',
            'mail-exist-show');

}]);
```

mailexists is the ng-class for the text element in the HTML which should be shown or hidden depending on the server response:

```
<p ng-class="mailexist">Text Text text Text</p>
```

The function in the controller is being invoked but The Text doesn't appear. If I add the $scope in the factory, then I get $scope is not defined which is true.
But $scope can't be injected in a factory/service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the success or error in the controller , just return the response

```
checkUser: function(elUrl, classHide, classShow){
  return  $http.post(elUrl)
}
```

handle in the controller

```
UserService.checkUser( 'inc/memberSearch.jsp?user.Email=' + $scope.umail + '&group.PK=' + angular.element('.grp').val(),
        $scope.mailexist,
        'mail-exist-hide',
        'mail-exist-show').then(function(){
            if (!response.data.isMember) {
        $scope.mailexits = 'mail-exist-hide'; 
        $('form').submit();
    } else {
        $scope.mailexits = 'mail-exist-show'; 
        return false;
    }
        }, function(response){
        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + response.data;
        });}]);
```

Comment: el = calssHide in the controller when calling and invoking the function shouldn't be: $scope.mailexits = 'mail-exist-hide'?

Comment: Error: response is not defined

Comment: Adding response as param in the function removed the error: response is not defined: .then(function(response){.... but the message is still not being displayed via: $scope.mailexits = 'mail-exist-show';

Comment: Working now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`factory` in `MVC` represents `model` and shouldn't be coupled with `view` - thing you are trying to achieve should be handled by `controller`

something like this should be ok:

```
var myApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myApp.factory("UserService", function ($http) {
    var users = ["xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz"];

    return {
        all: function () {
            return users;
            console.log( users );
        },
        first: function () {
            return users[1];
        },
        checkUser: function(elUrl, classHide, classShow){
            return $http.post(elUrl);
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', function ($scope, $http, UserService) {

UserService.checkUser( 'inc/memberSearch.jsp?user.Email=' + $scope.umail + '&group.PK=' + angular.element('.grp').val(),
            $scope.mailexist,
            'mail-exist-hide',
            'mail-exist-show').then(function(){
                // on success
            }, function(){
                // on error
            });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Send $scope as parameter to factory like

```
UserService.checkUser($scope,param1,..);
```

Than use this in factory

```
checkUser: function(scope,p1,...){
```

now use this scope in factory :) hope this will help

Comment: You can't send scope to factory for use two way binding. You need to use promise.

Comment: @Ujjwal kaushik: Thanks, it didn't help.

Comment: @hurricane My bad . It was working for in service. I didnt see this through for factory :(

Comment: One thing I still have to mention: The background of my concept is that I want to reuse the function in mutliple controllers.. so I don't want to write and invoke the same function in each controller...